# How to define current_user in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to print current user email in my RoR app. For this I did use the next code:

```
User.current_user
```

and it prints the next error: `undefined method`current_user' for #`

but when I used just `current_user` it doesn't print anything. I did search in Google and Stack, tried to use the answers of them, but nothing.

How can I get the user email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controllers, current_user alone will return the current signed in user. So current_user.email will return the email of the signed_in user. For non-signed in users, current_user will return nil.
To print the current user email in controller,

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def example
    p current_user.try(:email) # try is used because it will return nil if the user is signed in. otherwise, it will raise an error undefined method 'user' for nil class
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
User.current_user.email
```